keyword extraction and link to multiple sources
I have to perform a tech watch over a very rich subject which spans from software to deep physical issues and also, from business news to scientific articles.
Usually, I would have first retrieved the most encountered keywords of the subject and selected articles that matched them. But it fails to some extent as it is quite a rich subject and I may miss some important news and/or articles.
So, I try to have a different approach with the help of keyword extractors. I found 6 of them :

spaCy
YAKE
Rake-Nltk
Gensim
KeyBERT
TextRank

They all work with some text as input and a list of keywords is their outcome. However, this means that I would have to merge all articles, so that the information about in which article each keyword occur would be lost.
Is there a way to extract some keywords from many articles and being able to link keywords with each article where it appears ?
